# Is there a smart way to hide alot of text in HTML?

Tags: html

so I have this *huge* amount of text from several documents that i'd like to insert on my webpages. When i copy paste the text into my `<p>`element, it works fine and all, **but it looks messy in my html-file.**

Is there any other way to **transfer my written document to my html-file**, for instance link the document to the html-file, or maybe there's a way to hide or separate the `<p>` so the html-file looks neat even though there's a huge amount of text in my html-file. **Any advice?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know about any way to include html in another html (something like php's **include**), but it could be done with JQuery:

`index.html:`

```sh
<html> 
  <head> 
    <!-- link jquery -->
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#fileContent").load("doc.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="fileContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

`doc.html` (file that contains your text)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot you could do to separate these blocks of text.

Firstly, I'd recommend using `<div>..</div>` tags to divide the content into separate semantic sections. There are a bunch of different tags that aim to divide the content of the page semantically: `<aside>`, `<main>`, `<header>`, `<nav>`, and so on. I'd recommend reading up on these tags and using them appropriately.

However, to answer your question more directly, you should separate each block of text into separate `<p>` tags. After all, the `<p>` tag is meant for defining separate paragraphs. While the HTML document may not look pretty when indented and filled with multiple different tags like `<div>` a `<p>`, it is the best way to do it.

Unless the HTML page is going to be presented in its core (code) format, then how the `<p>` tags look in the `.html` file is unnecessary because after all these are what define how the page is presented and rendered in the browser.